# Execute SQL with "SELECT @daynamic_variable_name" in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Through the **exec** in SQL Server, I want to retrieve the parameter's value dynamically. Please look into the below Example:

```
declare @p1 varchar(50) = '10'
declare @p2 varchar(50) = '20'

declare @p_nm varchar(50)

set @p_nm = '@p1' -- OR set @p_nm = '@p2'
declare @sql varchar(50) = 'select @p1'

declare @ans_val varchar(50) 
set @ans_val = exec @sql
```

How could I get the result **10** if using **set @p_nm = '@p1'** and **20** if using **set @p_nm = '@p2'**?

In my case **set @ans_val = exec @sql** giving syntax error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A variable only has scope within the batch it is inside. When you run dynamic SQL, the dynamic SQL has a different scope, so variables cannot be accessed if they are in a different one. For example, both of the following statements will generate an error:

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX) = N'SELECT @i;';
DECLARE @i int = 1;
EXEC (@SQL);
GO

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX) = N'DECLARE @i int = 1;';
EXEC (@SQL);
SELECT @i;
GO
```

If you are running dynamic SQL, you need to pass details of any variables as parameters, using `sp_executesql`. For example:

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX) = N'SELECT @n;';
DECLARE @i int = 1;
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@n int', @n = @i;
```

If you want the return scalar values to a variable, use an `OUTPUT` parameter (personally, I recommend against the syntax `{Variable} = EXEC {Expression/Stored Procedure}`, one reason being you are therefore limited to one scalar value).

So, again, as an example:

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX) = N'SET @a =  @n + 1;';
DECLARE @i int = 1, @b int;
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@n int, @a int OUTPUT', @n = @i, @a = @b OUTPUT;
PRINT @b;
```

Comment: "SQL injection is not your friend! " - a quote from Larnu himself :) It wouldn't cause SQL injection, as yours wouldn't either.

Comment: @CetinBasoz Huh? I assume your comment in in reference to your (now deleted) answer? No, mine isn't open to injection. Your's, however, was (String concatenation like `declare @sql varchar(50) = 'select ' + @p_nm` is wide open. Imagine if `@p_nm` had the value `'1; USE Master; DROP DATABASE YourDatabase;'`). I *assume* the downvote is from you? Possibly you don't understand the implications of SQL Injection, or what it is: [SQL Inection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). I'd recommend reading up on it, as it's still far too common; even in this day and age.

Comment: If, @CetinBasoz , the downvote is from you, I'd really like to hear the feedback on why. What problems are there with what I've provided the OP? You didn't actually give a reason, and I really appreciate constructive criticism.

Comment: Thanks @Larnu, I got solution :-)

Comment: It was not an answer but a comment. As per the injection, you are wrong, mine was also based on parameters.

Comment: @CetinBasoz This seem to where you misunderstand SQL Injection then. Something like `declare @sql varchar(50) = 'select ' + @p_nm; exec sp_executesql @sql` is very much open to injection. Yes, `@sql` is a parameter, however, it wasn't a safe parameter; as it was generated by raw string concatenation. The value of `@p_nm`, could have been anything, and that *anything* would have been run by `sp_executesql`, regardless of if the intention was malicious. Just using `sp_executesql` doesn't make dynamic SQL safe. True Parametrisation and quoting (`QUOTENAME`) does.

Comment: @CetinBasoz here's an article from SSC on use of `QUOTENAME`, for example, when using objects. The article also, however, provides "bad" examples, and why they are so too: [Why `QUOTENAME` is important](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/QUOTENAME()/176104/). Hope you find it useful. Thanks for the discussion.

Comment: So what, those articles also shows why mine was parameter based.

Comment: @CetinBasoz it also shows why it was open to Injection. Im sorry if you don't understand, I've tried to help you anyway. I still certainly recommend looking into injection, it seems it's something you need to learn about. I don't appreciate the revenge vote, but hey, that's Stack Overflow...

Comment: You don't need to help me on injection. No need to repeat it was not open to injection but seems while you are trying to teach injection to others you really don't know what is open and what not and simply assume every string concatenation is open to attack. If you read that carefully you would see that what is appended itself is a parameter. Anyway I will revoke the down vote. I actually didn't deserve your down vote just as you didn't mine :) Now up voted hope you are happy.

Answer (score 3):

I'll do it like:

```
EXECUTE sp_executesql   
        N'SELECT @Var AS Result',
        N'@Var VARCHAR(5)',
        @Var = '12345';
```

Results:

```
+----+--------+
|    | Result |
+----+--------+
|  1 |  12345 |
+----+--------+
```

Or

```
DECLARE @Out VARCHAR(5);

EXECUTE sp_executesql   
        N'SELECT @Out = @Var',
        N'@Var VARCHAR(5) , @Out VARCHAR(5) OUTPUT',
        @Var = '12345',
        @Out = @Out OUTPUT;

SELECT @Out As Result;
```

Finally, please don't forgot to visit **[sp_executesql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#syntax)**